# GCP: if __name__ == '__main__' NOT WORKING

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-storage, google-cloud-run

I am trying to run a Python application on Google Cloud Run on GCP and the code includes an

```py
if __name__ == '__main__':
```

statement.  For some reason, the code after this statement does not run and

```py
print(__name__ == '__main__')
```

returns `'False'` while

```py
print(__name__)
```

returns `'main'`.

When I run the code in a Jupyter notebook,

```py
print(__name__ == '__main__')
```

returns `'True'` while

```py
print(__name__)
```

returns `'__main__'`.

Why does (i) `print(__name__ == '__main__')` return `'False'` and (ii) `print(__name__)` return `'main'` when the code is run on Google Cloud Run? And how does one fix this issue?

Comment: Edit your question and show your actual code correctly formatted. Remove tags for services that do not apply.

Comment: Please include your `Dockerfile`, specifically the `CMD` line.

Answer (score 4):

The value of `__name__` depends on how the file is being used. Consider the following file named `test.py`:

```py
# test.py
print(__name__)
```

If we run the file directly, we get:

```
$ python test.py
__main__
```

This will print `"__main__"` because the interpreter is running the file as the main program.

Instead, if we import the file:

```
$ python -c "import test"
test
```

This will print `test` as that's the name of the module we're importing.

I'm guessing that you have your Cloud Run application in a file named `main.py`, and that you're using `gunicorn` as an HTTP server. So when you specify something like:

```
CMD exec gunicorn --bind :$PORT main:app
```

This is telling `gunicorn` to import the `app` variable from the `main.py` file, and thus `__name__` will always be `"main"` in that file.

Depending on what you're doing in this `if __name__ == "__main__"` block, you could eliminate this check entirely and run the code inside it whenever the file is imported instead.

Answer (score 1):

> Before executing code, Python interpreter reads source file and define
>   few special variables/global variables, such as the `__name__` global variable.
>
> - If the python interpreter is running that module (the source file) as
>     the main program, it sets the special `__name__` variable to have a
>     value `“__main__”`.
> - If this file is being imported from another module, `__name__` will be
>     set to the module’s name.
>
> Module’s name is available as value to `__name__`  global variable.
>
> A module is a file containing Python definitions and statements.
>
> The file name is the module name with the suffix .py appended.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do?page=1&tab=votes#tab-top) you may find some examples in order to comprehend this process.

This might explain why when you run it from Jupyter notebook it is returning ‘true’ and whereas when it is run by the application on Cloud Run it is returning ‘false’.

Could you please specify how the script is being run and provide the code as requested by @John Hanley?